# Trying to get personal website color scheme to match Flux color temperature

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, hugo

I'm building a website in Hugo. I'm using the "tokiwa" theme as the template https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-theme-tokiwa/.

I have the software Flux on my computer (which adjusts the color temperature of the screen.) I like the way that template looks when the color temperature of flux is set to 1900K. I am not certain how to develop my site so that it appears that way even without flux being on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the color temperature to rgba conversion tool from

[here](https://academo.org/demos/colour-temperature-relationship/) and [here](https://tannerhelland.com/2012/09/18/convert-temperature-rgb-algorithm-code.html)

then write a custom.css file making a filter of that color

```
.flux-overlay{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 155, 61, 5%);
}

.flux-background{

    background: rgba(255, 155, 61, 5%);
}
```